# Powershell Strange behaviour with Import-CSV

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, import, powershell-3.0

I have following powershell code:

```
clear;
$importedIDs = (Import-Csv "testing.csv" -Delimiter ';').id;

Write-Host $importedIDs.Length;

for ($i=0; $i -lt $importedIDs.Length; $i++) {
  Write-Host $($importedIDs[$i]);
}
```

The goal is to read only the id column in the csv file which looks like this:

```
"created";"id"
"2018-04-04 21:03:01";"123456"
"2018-04-04 21:03:01";"123457"
```

When there are two or more rows the output is as expected:

```
2
123456
123457
```

However when there is only 1 row in the csv file (row with id 123456) the output is:

```
6
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Desired output would be:

```
1
123456
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how can I fix this?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple rows in the csv you get an array of strings. One array-element per row. Therefore the index applies to the rows. If there is only one row you don't get a array containing one string, as you would probably expect. You get a single string instead. When using an index on a string powershell treats the string as an array of characters and therefore returns only one char.

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly rewrite your script to get around the problem described by J. Bergmann.

Instead of using a `for` loop to loop through each element in the array, where an "element" may refer to a string in a string array or a character in a string, you can use a `foreach` loop and loop through elements in an array like this. `foreach` won't treat a string as an character array

```
clear;
$importedIDs = (Import-Csv "testing.csv" -Delimiter ';').id;

Write-Host $importedIDs.Length;

foreach ($importedID in $importedIDs) {
  Write-Host $($importedID);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I did